# Issue of undefined index while using ajax and php

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

I have four different files

index.php

select.php

insert.php

edit.php

delete.php

In my backend I have created a database named '***ecc***'

Database '***ecc***' has atable named '***task***'

The table task has following fields

***id, name, category, cost***

***Datatype for  id set to int and index as primary also id field is on auto increment***

My issue :( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\select.php on line 38

and same for lines 39, 40, 41,

each of the error is displayed twice on the page.

***index.php***

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">Live Table Add Edit Delete using Ajax Jquery in PHP Mysql</h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      fetch_data();  
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
           var name = $('#name').text();  
           var category = $('#category').text();  
           if(name == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter service Name");  
                return false;  
           }  
           if(category == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter category");  
                return false;  
           }  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"insert.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{name:name, category:category},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     fetch_data();  
                }  
           })  
      });  
      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"edit.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      $(document).on('blur', '.name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id1");  
           var name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, name, "name");  
      });  
      $(document).on('blur', '.category', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var category = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id,category, "category");  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
           var id=$(this).data("id3");  
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"delete.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{id:id},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data){  
                          alert(data);  
                          fetch_data();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

***select.php***

```
<?php  

 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','ecc');
    mysqli_select_db($connect,'ecc');

                if(!$connect){
                    echo "yes";
                }else{
                    echo "no";
                }

 $output = '';  

 $sql = "SELECT name, category FROM addservices ORDER BY id DESC";  

 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Service Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Category</th>  
                     <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
                </tr>';  


 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="category" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["category"].'</td>  
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td id="category" contenteditable></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error `Undefined index: id`

Because you have not put `id` in select query

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name, category FROM addservices ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Chek your query.It need to change as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is OK for testing, but never a good idea in a production environment.

Comment: @MrLister you are right, but Saloni is using all the columns name

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not selected "id" field in the $sql statement.
You have writen -

`$sql = "SELECT name, category FROM addservices ORDER BY id DESC";`

It should be

`$sql = "SELECT id, name, category FROM addservices ORDER BY id DESC";`